# Cannot use pdo_sqlite driver from PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, driver

When I uncomment `pdo_sqlite` line in `php.ini` I am getting

> Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20131226 PHP
>   compiled with module API=20121212 These options need to match

..when trying to access my `sqlite` database from `FatFree` framework.

How should I resolve this, tried to rebuild extension using `pecl` without
success.

`php -v` gives this:

> PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan 10 2014 15:37:29)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

I should just add, PDO works fine with `mysql`.

ADDITION:

```
pecl upgrade pdo_sqlite
```

fails, with:

> Makefile:183: recipe for target 'sqlite_driver.lo' failed
>   make: *** [sqlite_driver.lo] Error 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: I am on Linux, and yes there is `pdo_sqlite.so` under `/usr/lib/php/modules`.

Comment: What flavor of Linux

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module **API=20131226** PHP compiled with module **API=20121212** These options need to match

This error means your extension was compiled in a later version of PHP. You need to make sure your extensions match the version you're using.

Comment: I am aware of that, can you please tell me how to approach that, as I cannot find source for `pdo_sqlite` extension to `phpize`-it

Comment: If I had to guess, you probably have a version for 5.6 installed under 5.5. In CentOS this would be under `php-pdo` but I'm not familiar enough with Arch. Maybe try reinstalling PHP